# Unable to resolve JNDI name for Queue and QueueConnectionFactory in Weblogic

Tags: java, ejb

I am working on the example of Message Driven Bean in EJB. I created EJB project which is deployed in weblogic server and Client project which sends the message to MDB using JNDI name. I also created JMS Queue and Queue ConnectionFactory in weblogic console.

But problem is in client side it is not able to identify JNDI name for Queue.

[image: Weblogic Console]

**OueueListenerMDB.java on EJB Project**

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue")
    },
    mappedName = "mdb")
public class QueueListenerMDB implements IQueueListenerMDB{
public QueueListenerMDB() {
}

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            System.out.println("Queue: I received a TextMessage at "
                    + new Date());
            TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Message is : " + msg.getText());
        } else if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            System.out.println("Queue: I received an ObjectMessage at "
                    + new Date());
            ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
            Employee employee = (Employee) msg.getObject();
            System.out.println("Employee Details: ");
            System.out.println(employee);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not valid message for this Queue MDB");
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**QueueSenderDemo.java on client project**

```
public class QueueSenderDemo {
private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "t3://localhost:7002/";

private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

private static Context initialContext;

private static final String QUEUE_LOOKUP = "jms/weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue"; 
private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory"; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    sendMessageToQueue();
}

public static void sendMessageToQueue() {
    try {
        Context context = getInitialContextForClient();

        QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);

        QueueConnection connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false,
                QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(QUEUE_LOOKUP);

        QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Welcome to EJB3 Message Driven Bean.");
        sender.send(message);
        session.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Context getInitialContextForClient()
        throws NamingException {
    if (initialContext == null) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
        initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);
    }
    return initialContext;
}
}
```

I'm getting Error while running client program like this.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue' didn't find subcontext 'wsee'. Resolved 'jms.weblogic' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue' didn't find subcontext 'wsee'. Resolved 'jms.weblogic']; remaining name 'wsee/DefaultQueue'
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1035_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:423)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.mdbclient.utility.QueueSenderDemo.sendMessageToQueue(QueueSenderDemo.java:36)
at com.mdbclient.utility.QueueSenderDemo.main(QueueSenderDemo.java:27)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue' didn't find subcontext 'wsee'. Resolved 'jms.weblogic'
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your subdeployment / targeting is pointing to the correct server. Your queue might be hosted on a managed server and you are trying to lookup on the wrong managed server or admin server. If you could show the targeting or your jndi tree it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks you Miguel.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped a little :).

Comment: was there a solution to this question?

Comment: Don't think so. If you are having similar issues I can try to help.